# jQuery fire checkbox click with value

Tags: jquery

I need to fire a checkbox click by value to open a dialog...can someone explain why this is not working?

form:

```
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap obj">
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-exclusive-checkbox">
        <span class="wpcf7-list-item first">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="obj" value="Value 1" />
                <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Value 1</span>
            </label>
        </span>
        <span class="wpcf7-list-item">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="obj" value="Value 2" />
                <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Value 2</span>
            </label>
        </span>
        <span class="wpcf7-list-item last">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="obj" value="Other" />
                <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Other</span>
            </label>
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("input[type=checkbox][value='Value 1']").on('click',function() {
        alert('abcd');
    });
});
```

Comment: Is this checkbox added in the DOM after document is ready? If ya, delegate event

Comment: Your code works http://jsfiddle.net/gM67Y/ and Ideally you should use `change` event

Comment: can you add `console.log('length:', $("input[type=checkbox][value='Value 1']").length)` before adding the click handler

Comment: thanks @Satpal , it is not working locally...looks like i should search for some other issue then...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to delegate event, e.g:

```
$(document).on('click', "input[type=checkbox][value='Value 1']", function() {
        alert('abcd');
    });
```

Please read: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/